# DNS Server in Docker Container

Tags: docker, dns

I have the DNS server Unbound in a docker container. This container has the following port mapping in the docker deamon:
0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/udp

The docker host has the IP address 192.168.24.5 and a local DHCP server announces the host's IP as the local DNS server. This works fine all over my local network.
The host itself uses this DNS server through the IP 192.168.24.5. That's the address that is put to the host's /etc/resolv.conf. (I know it would not work with docker if there was 127.0.0.1 as the nameserver address.)

I have some other docker containers and they are supposed to use this DNS server as well. The point is, they don't.

What actually happens is this:
Whithin a random container I can ping the host's address as well as the address of the unbound-container. But when I use dig inside a container I get these results:

`# dig @172.17.0.6 ...
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 22778
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available`

`# dig @192.168.24.5 ...
;; reply from unexpected source: 172.17.0.1#53, expected 192.168.24.5#53`

This looks like some internal DNS server intercepts the queries and tries to answer them. That would be fine if it would use the host's DNS server to get an answer, but it doesn't. DNS doesn't work at all in the containers.

Am I doing wrong or is docker doing something it should not ?

Comment: In the container's /etc/resolv.conf the correct nameserver 192.168.24.5 appears. But that's probably of little use when it is not possible to ask it from within the container.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is iptables UDP nat for DNS server. You're querying the host IP while it's the docker bridge network's response.

To fix this issue in at least to ways:

- Use container IP (DNS container) as DNS resolver if possible.

or

- Provide `--net=host` to your DNS server container and remove port mapping altogether. Then host IP DNS would work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried both ways. 
1. I configured the container IP (172.17.0.6) as the host's nameserver. This change is reflected in the /etc/resolv.conf in the containers. But name resolution does not work on the host or in the containers this way. 
2. This solution is a bit against the dockerization idea. But the thing is, it does not work either (within other containers). There seems to be no difference between using the host's network stack or mapping port 53.

Can you explain what iptables exactly does with the DNS queries or point to a document about this issue ?

Comment: That's strange, I actually tried both ways and they work!
IPtables forwards the request to host IP to the container, that's why you get that error from your resolver.

Comment: I think using different network capabilities of docker like host networking is not against dockerizing the system. In different use cases (like NS) you may need to do that.